# exec("su") permission denied?

Tags: android, su, root

when I use this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su").
```

and listen to the ErrorStream it gives me back: Permission denied. However SuperUser successfully grants permissions. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ROM was messed up. I had to reinstall it. Adding a permission should **NOT** help.
Edit: SuperUser is now giving warning if you don't define the permission, how ever it will still grant su.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your ***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
```

Comment: Where is this permission documented?

Comment: @mice - That permission is not part of the Android, rather its the SuperUser binary and app that listens for the permission and that triggers the accept/deny for an app that wants to execute a command that requires root privileges.

Comment: Thanks. Funny that starts by standard android.permission.* looking like Android system permission. They had probably choose different name.